# Which is the best way to java code generation using ftl?

Tags: java, xml, struts2, code-generation, freemarker

I´m writing to ask some advice about code generation

I have a Struts2 datagrid which use the dependency injection pattern. To edit the grid I have to insert the field in the view and add it to the control class.

I want to turn the grid into FTL, using freemarker and FMPP, so as to regenerate it using xml.

My problem is that I have to copy the code to FTL, and to mark and separate the files to insert the fields and properties.

But, it takes a lot of time to build this template, and I´m really in a hurry.  I was wondering if you could tell me if there´s a better method or a easier way to do that.

Thanks.